# Get index of a DOM object within a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I have a set of jQuery elements, like this:

```
Object[
 div.event_marker, 
 div.event_marker, 
 div.event_marker.selected, 
 div.event_marker, 
 div.event_marker
]
```

I need to get the element directly before and/or directly after `.selected`.

I know that I can do this with `$elements.eq(n+1)` or `...(n-1)` where n is equal to the index of `.selected` within my jQuery object.

How do I get the n?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nzvj9t0x/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you build a fiddle demonstrating your need and making the question clearer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has a function to get the index of an element. That function is [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/).

Passing a DOM element to that function will search it in the current stack. so if you `.filter()` your selected element, you can then have your `n`:

```
var $all_markers = $('#markers .event_marker');
var n = $all_markers.index($all_markers.filter('.selected'));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been looking for :).

Answer (score 0):

Don't look inside your set, look in the DOM.

You can use

```
$myJquerySet.find('.selected').prev()
```

or

```
$myJquerySet.find('.selected').next()
```

Comment: But can be different depending what is the matched set

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, but it makes little sense to answer what is really asked because it's most certainly not what is needed. That's why I asked for some clarification. EDIT: it seems the fiddle confirms my doubt

Comment: @DenysSéguret sorry, the question was not clear enough. Nevertheless thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is match the elements with a selector and then use the .index() function to retrieve the position in the list.

You could do it like this:

```
var index = $myJquerySet.find('.selected').index();
$elements.eq(index + 1);
```

That should get the element after `.selected`